# Python: assigning multiple variables at once

Tags: python, variables

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = ''.join(doc[a1]),''.join(doc[a2]),''.join(doc[a3]),''.join(doc[a4]),''.join(doc[a5]),''.join(doc[a6]),''.join(doc[a7]),''.join(doc[a8]),''.join(doc[a9]),''.join(doc[a10])
```

How can I assign above values if it's needed to assign more than (let's say) 100 values or so?

Comment: Please don't do whatever you're trying to do. Can you show the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? I assure you that a list is probably what you want instead of 100 independently named variables.

Comment: Not like that. That would be terrible to have to read.

Comment: @CoryKramer Suppose I have csv file that has 100 string rows inside. What I'm trying to do is to select 50 of them randomly and assign it to 50 variables.

Comment: @KevinOelen Again I ask, why 50 variables instead of a single list with 50 elements?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a bit confusing. It would be more clear to do:

```
a = ''.join(doc[a1])
b = ''.join(doc[a2])
c = ''.join(doc[a3])
d = ''.join(doc[a4])
e = ''.join(doc[a5])
f = ''.join(doc[a6])
g = ''.join(doc[a7])
h = ''.join(doc[a8])
i = ''.join(doc[a9])
j = ''.join(doc[a10])
```

The syntax you're using is usually used in instances like:

```
str_ = "a,b"
a, b = str_.split(",")
# a = "a", b = "b"
```

What you want sounds like it could be handled by an array, but you'll have to turn a1,a2,...,a10 into an array.

Assuming a1,a2,...,a10 were in an array named `a` you could get what you want into an array called b by doing:

```
b = [''.join(doc(a_part)) for a_part in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use assignment, the pythonic way is using a dictionary.if `doc` is a dictionary you can loop over its values and use `enumerate` to create a dictionary :

```
d={}
for i,j in enumerate(doc.values()):
  d['a{}'.format(i)]=''.join(j)
```

If `doc` is not a dictionary and is another type of iterable objects you can just loop over itself.

You can also do it within a dict comprehension :

```
d={'a{}'.format(i):''.join(j) for i,j in enumerate(doc.values())}
```

And then you can simply access to your variables with indexing :

```
print d['a1'] # or d['an']
```

Comment: I think you forgot the colon after `for i,j in enumerate(doc.values())`.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very unreadable way to do that. Plus, you're trying to do something manually that you should be trying to do programmatically. Loops and lists are your friend. You don't want to have to keep track of that many variables. Rather it is more convenient to keep track of items in a list. You'd be better served with something like this:

```
new_list = []
for key in doc:
    new_list.append(''.join(doc[key]))
```

which can be written more succinctly as

```
new_list = [''.join(doc[key]) for key in doc]
```

or if doc is a list:

```
new_list = [''.join(item) for item in doc]
```